# Log saturado con warnings en PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, warnings

actualmente estoy notando que en mi log se están generando un montón de warnings y todos con el mismo mensaje:

**getimagesize(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/directorio/public_html/wp-content/plugins/td-cloud-library/shortcodes/header/tdb_header_logo.php on line 792**

**PHP Warning:  getimagesize(wp-content/uploads/2020/03/imagen_blanco1.png): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/cdirectorio/public_html/wp-content/plugins/td-cloud-library/shortcodes/header/tdb_header_logo.php on line 792**

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, lo agradeceria bastante.

Comment: Puede que esta [pagina te ayude](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-error-310/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, la verificó ahora.
Saludos.

Comment: Al parecer tienes un plugin que necesitas que tengas activado `allow_url_fopen`, es una configuración delicada, que da permisos para ejecutar archivos remotos en tu servidor. Debes asegurarte bien que ese plugin lo necesitas realmente, que está actualizado y que es seguro o de lo contrario te puedes llevar una sorpresa desagradable.

Comment: Es algo de lo que estuve leyendo, que activar esa función, puede abrir una gran brecha de seguridad.

Comment: Así es. No sé lo que hace ese plugin pero yo no estaría tranquilo con un plugin que se atribuye ese tipo de permisos, a no ser que realmente necesites permitir que servidores/dominios externos carguen archivos en tu servidor. En ese caso debes establecer controles de seguridad. La mayoría de sitios de WP son hackeados por plugins obsoletos o mal programados.

Comment: ese plugin realmente lo que hace es como llevar el control de las imágenes del sitio, este trabaja en conjunto con otros dos uno que convierte el codigo wp a algo que ya se puede ver para el usuario final, quiero pensar que si es bueno dale el acceso ya que ese es el único warning que sale y es lo único que se escribe en el log